# Is it okay to use App Tamer to force apps such as Microsoft Word, to "App Nap?"

Tags: macos, applications, utilities, app-nap

One (of the many) things which has always annoyed me about Microsoft Word 2016 (and indeed, pretty much all others apps in the Microsoft Office suite) is its inability to keep the background CPU usage to zero. When using Apple's Pages, Numbers, and Keynote, the CPU usage of each of the apps decreases to zero after you switch to another app. However, the apps in the Microsoft suite seem to use around half a percent of CPU on my laptop (which sometimes even spikes).

I recently found out about a cool app called [App Tamer](http://www.stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/) which seems like it can force an application to nap. As a matter of fact, one of the default rules seems to do this when you install App Tamer!

Now, I'm wondering if there are any unforeseen disadvantages of doing this. Does Microsoft cause this constant background CPU usage because essential (such as auto recover?) processes are taking place, or is it just a byproduct of sloppy, unoptimized coding? To be fair with the auto recovery example, however, I have empirically found it to be quite unreliable (unfortunately in the hard way).